# how to write regular expression for 1st letter upper case and remaining are lower case for validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

```
    var fn=document.forms["myForm"]["first"].value;

    if(!/(^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{29})/g.test(a)){
    document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML="Regular expression 
    mismatched";
    document.getElementById('first').focus();
    return false;
    }
```

im trying with this in eclipse but no result

Answer (score 1):

You could try ->

`/(^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*$)/g`

Your current test was wanting exactly 29 lowercase characters.
Here I've modified for any with the `*`, and then asked util end also lowercase with the `$`

Comment: i dont know where im wrong any of this answer are not working for me...im using  Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your missing a $ ath the end.

Try this:

`/[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,29}$/g.test(a)`

Where {1,29} is the range of the length of the lower case letter string.